# CursorAdapter with two row layouts

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

Okey so, since I've not found a consistent way of doing this when I searched, I decided that maybe putting my code for somebody elses eyes to see might help.

I'm creating a game where you use cards. These cards can either be locked or unlocked depending on different factors. The important thing is, that I want to check the sqlite db whether they are locked, then display different row layouts for the two possible outcomes.

Here's my code:

```
public class AllCardsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

LockedHolder viewLocked;
UnlockedHolder viewUnlocked;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
public static final int LOCKED = 0;
public static final int UNLOCKED = 1;

public AllCardsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final int type;

    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("unlocked")));

    if (viewType == 1){
        type = UNLOCKED;
    } else {
        type = LOCKED;
    }

    if (type == LOCKED){
        viewLocked = (LockedHolder) view.getTag();
        viewLocked.nameHolder.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        viewLocked.awardedAtHolder.setText("Awarded at level:");
        viewLocked.reqLvlHolder.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("reqlvl")));

        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));

        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_1")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_1).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewLocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_2")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_2).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewLocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_3")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_3).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewLocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_slowdown")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_slowdown).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewLocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_speed_up")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_speed_up).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewLocked.imageHolder);
        }

    } else {
        viewUnlocked = (UnlockedHolder) view.getTag();
        viewUnlocked.nameHolder.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));

        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_1")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_1).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewUnlocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_2")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_2).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewUnlocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_obj_plus_3")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_obj_plus_3).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewUnlocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_slowdown")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_slowdown).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewUnlocked.imageHolder);
        }
        if (imagePath.equals("card_speed_up")){
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.card_speed_up).placeholder(R.drawable.card_placeholder).into(viewUnlocked.imageHolder);
        }

    }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewLocked = new LockedHolder();
    viewUnlocked = new UnlockedHolder();
    final int type;

    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("unlocked")));

    if (viewType == 1){
        type = UNLOCKED;
    } else {
        type = LOCKED;
    }
    System.out.println(viewType);
    System.out.println(type);

    if (type == LOCKED){
        View lockedView;
        lockedView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list_row_disabled, parent, false);
        viewLocked.nameHolder = (TextView) lockedView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        viewLocked.imageHolder = (ImageView) lockedView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        viewLocked.reqLvlHolder = (TextView) lockedView.findViewById(R.id.tvLevelNr);
        viewLocked.awardedAtHolder = (TextView) lockedView.findViewById(R.id.tvAwardedAt);
        lockedView.setTag(viewLocked);

        return lockedView;
    } else {
        View unlockedView;
        unlockedView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list_row, parent, false);
        viewUnlocked.nameHolder = (TextView) unlockedView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        viewUnlocked.imageHolder = (ImageView) unlockedView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        unlockedView.setTag(viewUnlocked);

        return unlockedView;
    }

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}

public class LockedHolder {
    public TextView nameHolder;
    public ImageView imageHolder;
    public TextView awardedAtHolder;
    public TextView reqLvlHolder;
}

public class UnlockedHolder {
    public TextView nameHolder;
    public ImageView imageHolder;
}

}
```

The error I'm getting is on the row "viewLocked = (LockedHolder) view.getTag();"

AllCardsAdapter$UnlockedHolder cannot be cast to AllCardsAdapter$LockedHolder

The error only shows up when I have a list containing cards that are both locked and unlocked.

See I know what it's trying to do, I just don't know why. Also, if I'm overcomplicating things for no good reason, or missing something obvious, I'd be much appreciated if you find it..

Comment: That is because the view's tag for that position is set to an UnlockedHolder and you are trying to cast it back to a LockedHolder. I would try having a single view holder and have conditions inside of that view holder that determines how it is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*getItemViewType* implementation does not look right (type does not depend on item position) it should be something like the following

```
private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
    return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("unlocked")) % 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    return getItemViewType(cursor);
}
```

You also need to update *bindView* and *newView*

```
int viewType = this.getItemViewType(cursor);
```